# AutoCompleteTextView enter press

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In `EditText` `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/fuelfrom"` will goes to next field when press done, similarly, how can I make a `AutoCompleteTextView` goes to next field when pressing `enter` key...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

it will show focus on next field on pressing enter.

**EDIT:**

try this one

```
 android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Comment: `singleLine` deprecated

Comment: i have values which have more than 30 chars.By making it single line, cant see the entire value..

Comment: @JeevaV You can't use singleLine or imeOptions in this case.

Comment: try with  android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 1):

```
use this.

  <EditText android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
    android:inputType="text"/>
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { 

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

if  ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {

     Log.i(TAG,"Here you can write the code");
    }    
    return false;
}
});
```

should return true in the if clause to say you've handled i